# Password protect folder in android

Tags: android, directory

I want to store media files in an external storage creating a folder . The folder is secured using a password and accessible by my app only. The user is allowed to create its own password. Any suggestions how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach is possible. Maybe you should think about encrypting the file contents, so that only your app will be able do access the actual content after decryption.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting files is not a solution!  This only creates potential file loss and problems later.  Also, it is slow and you rely on the app that encrypted the files to unencrypt them later.  What if that app dies or is not longer available?  You have lost your files.

Answer (score 0):

External storage such as the SD card has no permissions associated with it. The closest you could do is to store your data in some encrypted form and as per requirement you can decrypt it also.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327370/how-can-i-lock-a-file-in-android/41328904#41328904) is the link for how you can encrypt and decrypt your file.